# How to install Open64 Compiler?

Tags: installation, compiler

Open64 is the compiler maintained by AMD, here are the links: http://developer.amd.com/tools/cpu-development/x86-open64-compiler-suite/ and the Community Maintained one http://www.open64.net/home.html

I would love to know how to install it. The instructions from this link: http://www.open64.net/documentation/installing-open64-424/building-the-compiler.html didn't work nor the instructions from the HOWTO-INSTALL-OPEN64 file, which are the same...

It returns error 127 and then error 2.

Comment: I want to point out that the community Open64 had no activity for a few years and seems like AMD's Open64 is unmaintained too...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I got the Open64 compiler built on my 64-bit system running Ubuntu 11.10 by following these steps that I pieced together from a few places:

Make sure you have prerequisites installed:

```
sudo apt-get install mawk csh bash make flex bison gfortran ia32-libs gcc-multilib g++-multilib gfortran-multilib
```

Make sure sh is linked to bash and not dash:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure dash
```

and select 'No'.

Make sure that awk is linked to mawk:

```
ls -al /etc/alternatives/awk
```

Fix looking for the crt libraries in the wrong locations by making symbolic links:

```
cd /usr/lib
sudo ln -s /usr/lib32/crt* .

sudo mkdir /usr/lib64/
cd /usr/lib64/
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt* .
```

Download the Open64 source and uncompress:

```
cd ~
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/open64/open64/Open64-5.0/open64-5.0-0.src.tar.bz2

tar xjvf open64-5.0-0.src.tar.bz2
cd open64-5.0/
```

Now make another directory inside this for building the compiler

```
mkdir objs
cd objs
```

Decide where you want to install, and run the configure script.  Replace /opt/open64/5.0 with where you want to install open64.  If you want to use the default location, leave off the --prefix argument.

```
../configure --prefix=/opt/open64/5.0
```

Now fix an unrecognized option error:

```
nano ../osprey/ipa/local/Makefile.gbase
```

and delete or comment out the last line containing:

```
ipl_summarize_util.o: OPTIMIZER += -CG:all_sched=0
```

Build the compiler (assuming an 8-core machine, -j 6 seems reasonable)

```
make -j 6
sudo make install
```

Comment: It worked, Thanks. Would be great if you will also add information how to add the binary to the PATH(http://www.codecoffee.com/tipsforlinux/articles/11.html) it will help the others who will find this post. Bounty in 23 hours.

Comment: Wow! That rocks :] Thanks a lot for this answer. On 12.04 it works as well.